# How to pass arguments to makefile

Tags: c, makefile, arguments

I write a c program in Codeblocks and in order to compile I use a custom makefile. I build the code from inside Codeblocks and it works fine until I add arguments (in Codeblocks or terminal) and they are not passed to the program. What should I add to the makefile to take the arguments into consideration? Hereby the

c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
    printf("\n%c\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lm

 all: Release

Debug: CFLAGS += -g
Debug: K

Release: K

K: K.o
    $(CC) -o K K.o $(LDFLAGS)

K.o: K.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) K.c -o K.o

clean:
    rm -f K.o K
```

Comment: But your `makefile` does not *run* the program. Are these arguments needed to *build* or to *run* the program?

Comment: No, it's only making the .o file. Then in terminal I run ./program and it works but ./program arg1 arg2 is not working (argc stays 0 instead of 3)

Comment: Then you should show us your code, not the `makefile`.

Comment: By the way, I am very sceptical about `Debug: CFLAGS += -g`. What is your intent here?

Comment: Are you certain the program you run is actually compiled by this makefile? Can't you just change the message in `printf()`, rebuild and re-run to check if it is really taken in consideration?

Comment: Try `"%d"` in `printf()`

Comment: `printf("\n%c\n", argv[0]);` is wrong. `%c` expects an `int` (containing a single character code), but `argv[0]` is a `char *` (pointing to a null-terminated array of `char` containing the name of the program).

Comment: In general, you should pass `$(CFLAGS)` to the linking command too; it ensures that arguments such as `-g` are passed to the linking phase — which matters.  Your program is using `%c` (print a single character) to print a string (`argv[0]` is a string containing the program name).  You should probably change `%c` to `%s`; failing that, you should print `argv[0][0]` rather than just `argv[0]`.  It is not clear how you are running your program; the `makefile` doesn't run it.

Comment: I suspect that you are attempting to be able to do `make debug` and make an executable with debugging enabled, and `make release` to build a version without debugging enabled.  I am highly suspicious of the two targets for `debug`  I've never seen anything like that in a make file.  As a start you could pass the "-n" flag to make (which will cause it to just print out the commands it is going to execute but not run those commands - you then have a chance to examine each of those commands and make sure that they are what you expect.

Comment: Hi all and thank you. Changing %c to %s solved the problem

Comment: @thurizas that syntax is fine (for GNU make): it's a target-specific variable assignment.  Read about it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Answer (score 1):

Your program as shown will not print any args passed on the command line. argv[0] is typically the name of the program, also %c is a single character format, you want %s.

Try this:

```
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
  printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
```